# How to create a header view for NSCollectionView

Tags: macos, nstableview, nscollectionview, nstableheaderview

I need to set a header view for my NSCollection view. When I researched I found that NSCollection view don't support a default header view like NSTableView. I need a header almost like the one used in skype. ie. apart from displaying just a title, I may need to perform some actions upon clicking header corresponding to a column. for eg. Sort by name upon clicking 'Name' column.

What is the best way to implement this if I subclass and create my own header view? Which view should I subClass to get both, the look and feel of NSTableview header and the clickable properties like that of NSButton?

Comment: I don't see these classes being available on iOS. Retagged.

Comment: yeah, These are OS x classes :)